# Laravel делает redirect после AJAX запроса

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

Всем привет, работаю на фреймворке `Laravel 5.5`

Есть ajax запрос, после вывода результата запроса, laravel редиректит на homepage.

При успешном ответе от ajax, в адресную строке добавляется знак "?"

Метод : POST

Кто - то сталкивался с этим ?

В чем проблема ?

```
userEmail = $('.signin-container #signin-email').val();
userPassword = $('.signin-container #signin-password').val();

$.ajax({
  headers: Route.header,
  url: Route.signIn,
  data: {
    method: POST,
    userEmail: userEmail,
    userPassword: userPassword
    }
}).done(function(data) {
        Api.makeSignin(data);
    });
```

----- сервер -----

```
$userData = [];
$userData['email'] = $request->userEmail;
$userData['password'] = $request->userPassword;


return $result;
```

Comment: А ты заголовок добавляешь ```'Accept' => 'application/json'```

Comment: нет, не добавляю, я читал про это но подумал что врядли будет изза этого, а куда его добавить, не подскажете добрый человек ?

Comment: headers, я обычно прям в глобальный добавляю ```$.ajaxSetup({headers: {"Accept": "application/json}}) ```, ну или тогда в headers для отдельного запроса

Comment: окей, а как их сгруппировать ? просто у меня в headers csrf token лежит

    header : { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },

Comment: как оказалось, в js его прописывать не обязательно, хватает и в html прямо, сейчас попробую ваш header

Comment: Ну вы там передаете объект, какая разница у него ж может быть ни одно поле

Comment: header : {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "X-CSRF-TOKEN": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },

Прописал, но странно, проблема осталась, если вот в web.php 

вместо /api/auth/signIn сделать /api/auth/signIn? проблемы не бывает..

просто это синтаксически неверно, добавлять к концу роута знак ?

Comment: после Ajax запроса в адресной строке появляется вопрос, не понимаю что происходит

Comment: Route.signIn ?  что у тебя тут ? это ты где то шлешь видать его изначально, либо это у тебя где в роутах js какая то беда, я думаю Lara тут ни при чем

Comment: Вот я сейчас убрал все лишнее, и вот что интересное увидел.

    $('#signin-submit-button').onclick(function() {

      alert('test');

после того как срабатывает onclick в адресной строке появляется знак вопроса, и страница перегружается .
как такое может быть ?

Comment: спасибо за помощь, кнопка button была в пустом тэгэ form.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался.

Решение было в том, что

кнопка button была расположена в пустом тэге form, он и перезагружал страницу.

```
    <form>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign In</button>
    </form>
```